# native-audio sample in NDK build problem

Tags: android, android-ndk

i have a problem when build native-audio sample in NDK.
The main reason is "SLES/OpenSLES.h: No such file or directory"

I have googled but i dont find any thing helpful.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

If you are building from the commandline, try

ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-9

Comment: Currently I m using Android NDK(ndk10d) and eclipse i have try using command line but not able to resolve this issue.I got same issue. is there any other way? if I copied  SLES folder from Android NDK then error is resolve but i want to know is this the right way?

Comment: adding this to your Application.mk also helps                      APP_PLATFORM := android-9

Answer (score 5):

it is due to your android version . specify android version when build.

ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-9

Answer (score 3):

I've also got this problem but now, it works.
You should use exactly the Android API 9.
In Eclipse, create a new project from existing source (the native-audio sample) whose target is Android 2.3.1, then, build the shared library with ndk-build. Finally build your project in Ecclipse by the common way to do that.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I want to build a native audio application for android 1.6. But as you said, it is impossible, isnt it ?

Comment: Yes it's impossible. It uses methods that expose the NativeAudio player interface which are included after API 9 - that's way there is Equalizer in API 9.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Android Studio` and an `Application.mk` file. Set the android platform version with:

```
//replace 'x' with the platform version you are targeting
APP_PLATFORM := android-x
```

[Click here](http://brian.io/android-ndk-r10c-docs/Programmers_Guide/html/md_3__key__topics__building__a_p_p_l_i_c_a_t_i_o_n-_m_k.html) for ndk-r10c reference. I am using ndk-r10e and it still uses the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio you can solve this problem by adding the following line to the **project.properties** file:

```
target=android-23 // replace 23 with the api you are targeting
```

the **project.properties** file should be located inside the "main" directory, if it's not there you can create the file and it should work fine.